# Sharing reports between users in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, cloud, report, admin, dashboard

An user has created few reports in salesforce and he has been removed(deactivated) from salesforce .So now i want to share his reports to some other user in salesforce.How can i do this. could someone help??

Answer (score 0):

The default save location for custom reports is "My Personal Custom Reports." That is a private folder that only the authoring user can access. To share reports, they need to be saved to a public folder.
In your scenario (assuming these reports are in the private folder), first create a public report folder, then login as the user (you will need to reactivate them first), and go into their "My Personal Custom Reports" folder. For each report you want to share, you'll need to open it and choose the "Save as" option, then select the public folder as the destination. A new copy of the report will then be available to anyone with access to that folder.
If the reports are already in a public folder, you simply need to give other users permissions to that folder.